# Using multiple didBegin contact - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-engine

I would like to have so SKSpriteNodes can take care of there own contact detection.
Much like Unity have there own `OnTriggerEnter` methods on there GameObjects.
But I do not know how to achieve that in SpriteKit, some help would much appriciated

Example how I would "like" it to work:

example Ball class:

```
import SpriteKit

class Ball: SKSpriteNode, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("INSIDE BALL: ",contact.bodyA.node?.name, contact.bodyB.node?.name)
    }

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self ????

     //setting up Physicsbody etc
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

example scene file

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("INSIDE MAIN: ",contact.bodyA.node?.name, contact.bodyB.node?.name)
    }
```

Or how do you manage large amount of contact logic?

Thanks for any help and sorry if the questions is weirdly formulated

Answer (score 1):

I like to structure my `didBegin` code this way: (the objects that can contact are blueBall, blueRectangle, greenBall, greenRectangle, redBall and redRectangle)

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {

    case blueBallCategory | blueRectangleCategory:
       print("Alive! Blue ball has hit blue rectangle.")

    case greenBallCategory | greenRectangleCategory:
       print("Alive! Green ball has hit green rectangle.")

    case redBallCategory | redRectangleCategory:
       print("Alive! Red ball has hit red rectangle.")

    default :
        print("Dead! Some other contact has occurred")
    }
}
```

You could, of course, call separate functions inside each `case` statement if you have much more contact logic. Equally you could call a collision method in the object that has collided:

```
    case blueBallCategory | blueRectangleCategory:
       contact.bodyA.hasHit(contact.bodyB)
```

or similar.